# Splitting an array with N arrays of a value pair, into set N sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, split

Any help or suggestion on how to achieve please?

I have a group of 8 teams

```
    teamArray  =['Team_1', 'Team_2', 'Team_3', 'Team_4', 'Team_5', 'Team_6', 'Team_7', 'Team_8']
```

and use the following function to pair each team which give 28 pairs

```
    let pairs = teamArray.flatMap(
        (v, i) => teamArray.slice(i+1).map( w => [v,w] )
    );
```

Now I want to take the 28 pairs and split into 7 arrays of with 4 pairs, while each array cannot have an pair with one value more than once?

an example of the desired output:

```
result  = [
[['Team_1', 'Team_2'], ['Team_3', 'Team_4'], ['Team_5', 'Team_6'], ['Team_7', 'Team_8']],
[['Team_1', 'Team_3'], ['Team_2', 'Team_4'], ['Team_5', 'Team_7'], ['Team_6', 'Team_8']],
...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a task for the `reduce` method of an array:

```
result = pairs.reduce((accumulator, currentPair) => {
    let match = accumulator.find(array => !array.some(pair => currentPair.some(ci => pair.some(i => ci === i))));
    if (match !== undefined) {
        match.push(currentPair);
        return accumulator;
    }
    else {
        accumulator.push([currentPair]);
        return accumulator;
    }
}, []);
```